# Inconsistent error returning from 2 winapi calls

Tags: winapi, rust

This is my source code:

```
extern crate user32;
extern crate kernel32;

use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::ptr;

fn main() {
    let mut message = get_data();
    loop {
        if message != get_data() {
            let mut client = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
            message = get_data();
            println!("{}", message);
            let _ = client.write(message.as_bytes());
            println!("Sent!");
        }
    }
}

fn get_data() -> String {
    let value: String;
    unsafe {
        let open = user32::OpenClipboard(ptr::null_mut());
        if open == 0 {
            println!("{}", kernel32::GetLastError());
            user32::CloseClipboard();
            return "NULL".to_string()
        }
        let var = user32::GetClipboardData(13 as u32);
        if var.is_null() {
            println!("{}", kernel32::GetLastError());
            user32::CloseClipboard();
            return "NULL".to_string()
        }
        let data = kernel32::GlobalLock(var) as *mut u16;
        let len = rust_strlen16(data);
        let raws = std::slice::from_raw_parts(data, len);
        value = String::from_utf16_lossy(raws);
        kernel32::GlobalUnlock(var);
        user32::CloseClipboard();
    }
    value
}

#[inline(always)]                                       // used from clipboard-win, not mine
unsafe fn rust_strlen16(buff_p: *mut u16) -> usize {
    let mut i: isize = 0;
    while *buff_p.offset(i) != 0 {
        i += 1;
    }
    return i as usize
}
```

When I initialize `message` at line 1 of `main`, everything is fine, but when I start copying text, things start to get a little weird.

From the `OpenClipboard` function in `get_data()`, the errors I would get from `GetLastError` would either be 6 (`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`) or 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) for an unknown reason.

From the `GetClipboardData` function I would consistently get error code 1418 (`ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN`) from `GetLastError`. You would think that I would get this error from getting an error code 6 or 5 from `OpenClipboard`, however it wouldn't print 1418 since it can't go that far in the function, right? I might be wrong but that's how I see it.

Something you should also note is that these errors show up when comparing `message` in the loop, but the `if` statement continues anyway and the message gets assigned the actual copied data, here is some sample output.

```
1418  // this is when message and get_data() are being checked
println!("{}", result); // this is the actual copied data which is message
Sent! // sent!
5
NULL
Sent!
println!("Got Connection");
Sent!
```

Comment: As the author of the `user32` and `kernel32` crates, I can confidently say that there is no interop going on. They are raw direct calls that are linked directly to the system libraries. Zero wrapping, equivalent to using them from C.

Comment: @retep998 this is a strange problem. I've even got the code going into an infinite loop or not depending on if I have a `println!`. Something is mucked up somewhere...

Comment: Ugh, never mind my last thing. `println!` must eventually call something that changes `GetLastError`, as @DavidHeffernan was pointing out. Using `println!` between a WinAPI function and a call to `GetLastError` is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @Shep I'd expect the args to be prepared before the function is called

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I had something akin to `WinApiCall(); println!(); GetLastError();`, which in hindsight was a really dumb thing to do ^_^. It certainly got me confused. After fixing my own mistake, I'm still seeing issues where an "opened" clipboard isn't open, according to `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my **guess** as to what is happening: the system is forcibly closing your open clipboard handle.

As far as I have been able to tell, the clipboard is a *truly* global shared resource, even across processes. I can't trace how far back the `OpenClipboard` function came into existence, but it works on at least Windows 2000 according to MSDN. I wouldn't be surprised if it actually originated in Windows 98 / 95 or even before that. The clipboard is an old concept!

However, a conceptual problem arises: what if one program opens the clipboard and forgets to close it? Then your entire system would be prevented from using the clipboard, which would be pretty terrible. I believe (with **no proof**) that the OS tracks how much you've had the clipboard open and decides to take the clipboard back from you when you are hogging it.

When you run your program, you can see that it is pegged at 100% CPU, as you've constructed a busy loop that has the clipboard open for the majority of the time. That would be enough to trigger a simple abuse heuristic. Adding (`::std::thread::sleep_ms(100)`) to the end of your loop seems to make everything behave much nicer.

However, you do still get error code 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) sporadically. Again, I believe this to be caused by the global shared nature of the clipboard. Some *other* process has opened the clipboard for some reason and you cannot have it. The correct thing there is to handle not being able to always get immediate access to the resource.

Making those changes seem to get your program working, but there's more to be done:

```
extern crate user32;
extern crate kernel32;

use std::ptr;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

fn main() {
    let mut sequence_val = None;

    loop {
        let clip = match Clipboard::open() {
            Err(WinApiError(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)) |
            Err(WinApiError(ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN)) => {
                println!("Someone else is using the clipboard; continuing");
                continue;
            },
            Err(e) => panic!("Unknown error while opening the clipboard: {:?}", e),
            Ok(c) => c,
        };

        let next_sequence_val = Some(clip.sequence_number());
        if sequence_val != next_sequence_val {
            println!("Clipboard advanced from {:?} to {:?}", sequence_val, next_sequence_val);
            sequence_val = next_sequence_val;

            let all_formats: Result<Vec<_>, _> = clip.formats().collect();
            println!("Available formats: {:?}", all_formats);

            let message = clip.get_text().expect("Cannot read from clipboard");

            match message {
                Some(message) => println!("Got clipboard text: {}", message),
                None          => println!("Clipboard did not contain textual data"),
            }
        }

        ::std::thread::sleep_ms(250);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct WinApiError(u32);

const ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED: u32 = 0x5;
const ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN: u32 = 0x58A;

impl WinApiError {
    fn from_global() -> Result<(), WinApiError> {
        let val = unsafe { kernel32::GetLastError() };
        if val != 0 {
            Err(WinApiError(val))
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

// PhantomData is used here to prevent creating the struct with
// `Clipboard`.
struct Clipboard {
    marker: PhantomData<()>,
}

const CF_UNICODETEXT: u32 = 13;

impl Clipboard {
    fn open() -> Result<Clipboard, WinApiError> {
        unsafe {
            user32::OpenClipboard(ptr::null_mut());
            try!(WinApiError::from_global());
            Ok(Clipboard { marker: PhantomData })
        }
    }

    fn formats(&self) -> ClipboardFormats {
        ClipboardFormats { clip: PhantomData, fmt: 0 }
    }

    fn sequence_number(&self) -> u32 {
        unsafe { user32::GetClipboardSequenceNumber() }
    }

    fn get_text(&self) -> Result<Option<String>, WinApiError> {
        for fmt in self.formats() {
            let fmt = try!(fmt);
            if fmt == CF_UNICODETEXT {
                unsafe {
                    let var = user32::GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
                    try!(WinApiError::from_global());

                    // I don't believe this lock is actually
                    // needed. In searching around, it only seems to
                    // be used when you call `GlobalAlloc` and then
                    // set the clipboard with that data.

                    // If it's needed, consider making another RAII
                    // type to handle automatically unlocking.
                    let data = kernel32::GlobalLock(var) as *mut u16;
                    try!(WinApiError::from_global());

                    let len = rust_strlen16(data);
                    let raws = std::slice::from_raw_parts(data, len);
                    let value = String::from_utf16_lossy(raws);

                    kernel32::GlobalUnlock(var);
                    try!(WinApiError::from_global());

                    return Ok(Some(value));
                }
            }
        }

        Ok(None)
    }
}

impl Drop for Clipboard {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            // Ignore failure to close as we can't really do anything
            // about it
            user32::CloseClipboard();
            let _ = WinApiError::from_global();

        }
    }
}

unsafe fn rust_strlen16(buff_p: *mut u16) -> usize {
    let mut i = 0;
    while *buff_p.offset(i) != 0 { i += 1 }
    i as usize
}

struct ClipboardFormats<'a>{
    // PhantomData is used here to prevent outliving the opened
    // clipboard
    clip: PhantomData<&'a Clipboard>,
    fmt: u32,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ClipboardFormats<'a> {
    type Item = Result<u32, WinApiError>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let next_fmt = unsafe { user32::EnumClipboardFormats(self.fmt) };
        if next_fmt == 0 {
            match WinApiError::from_global() {
                Ok(_) => None,
                Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
            }
        } else {
            self.fmt = next_fmt;
            Some(Ok(next_fmt))
        }
    }
}
```

Namely I created a convenience type `WinApiError` that checks `GetLastError` automatically and ties it into the Rust-standard `Result` type. This is used pervasively along with `try!`.

I introduced a `Clipboard` struct to have a type to implement `Drop` on. This makes it certain that we will *always* close the clipboard when we are done with it. You may want to even add a `close` method that makes it very obvious and easy if you want to close it earlier:

```
fn close(self) {
    // Automatically dropped as it goes out of scope.
}
```

To improve performance slightly, I used `GetClipboardSequenceNumber` which returns an integer timestamp for the clipboard. This allows for a lighter-weight check to know if the clipboard has changed, instead of creating a `String` each time. It also prevents you from having a magic string of `"NULL"`. You may still want to keep track of the last string to know if the user has copied the same text again.

When retrieving data from the clipboard, you should iterate through all the available formats and take action on the first you care about. Although you only care about the UCS-2 format, I added this while attempting to debug so I figured I'd leave it.

There is a better solution than just sleeping that I have not implemented. [`AddClipboardFormatListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033(v=vs.85).aspx) can notify a message loop when the clipboard changes. This is probably the correct solution, but does require you to create a window (even if it's used only for messages).

Comment: I do have a question about PhantomData however, why is it needed?

Comment: @Vikaton I added basic explanation comments in each use of `PhantomData`; which of those should be made more explicit?

Comment: the declaration of `struct Clipboard<PhantomData<()>)`

Comment: @Vikaton the answer was a bit longer, so I [posted it separately](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34603635/155423).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Vikaton/a02845839d23af2d5286 I'm consistently getting error 1418 :(

Comment: @Vikaton :-( indeed. I see the same stuff in my VM. I think you want to allow both types of errors when trying to open the clipboard and just retry. I've modified this answer, but I note that your code removed that check and retry logic.

Comment: Yeah that check and retry logic indeed worked, I always get some sort of error but it ends up sending the data, thanks! This has been very weird since I dont know why things just didnt work :(

Comment: @Vikaton I hear you! And there's not a lot of existing posts that say "oh yeah, that function fails half the time; just retry", which makes it seem like our code is doing the wrong thing...