# Why would I create a struct with only a `PhantomData<()>` member?

Tags: rust

While reading [the answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582221/155423), I saw this construct [1]:

```
struct Clipboard {
    marker: PhantomData<()>,
}
```

While I've seen other uses of [`PhantomData`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html), all of them have been parameterized with an interesting type, like `PhantomData<&'a [u8]>` or `PhantomData<T>`. Why would you want to create struct that *acts* as if it contains an empty tuple?

[1]: A bit of poetic license as I actually *wrote* the other answer, but was asked to explain why I did what I did. It was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the clipboard was a globally shared resource that didn't give you any token when you opened it. To try and use the clipboard without opening it first would be a Bad Thing. If you did the straightforward thing and created an empty struct, then you could *forget* to call the proper constructor method:

```
struct Clipboard;

impl Clipboard {
    fn new() -> Clipboard {
        println!("Clipboard opened");
        Clipboard
    }

    fn copy(&self) -> String { "copied".into() }
}

let c = Clipboard::new(); // Correct
println!("{}", c.copy());
let c = Clipboard;        // Nope, didn't open the clipboard properly
println!("{}", c.copy()); // But can still call methods!?!?!
```

Let's try a tuple struct with a dummy value inside:

```
struct ClipboardWithDummyTuple(());

impl ClipboardWithDummyTuple {
    fn new() -> ClipboardWithDummyTuple {
        println!("Clipboard opened");
        ClipboardWithDummyTuple(())
    }

    fn copy(&self) -> String { "copied".into() }
}

let c = ClipboardWithDummyTuple::new(); // Correct
println!("{}", c.copy());
let c = ClipboardWithDummyTuple;
println!("{}", c.copy()); // Fails here
// But because `c` is a method, not an instance
```

This is better, but the error occurs later than we'd like; it only happens when we try to use the clipboard, not when we try to construct it. Let's try making a struct with named fields:

```
struct ClipboardWithDummyStruct { 
    // warning: struct field is never used
    dummy: (),
}

impl ClipboardWithDummyStruct {
    fn new() -> ClipboardWithDummyStruct {
        println!("Clipboard opened");
        ClipboardWithDummyStruct { dummy: () }
    }

    fn copy(&self) -> String { "copied".into() }
}

let c = ClipboardWithDummyStruct::new(); // Correct
println!("{}", c.copy());
let c = ClipboardWithDummyStruct; // Fails here
// But we have an "unused field" warning
```

So, we are closer, but this would generate a warning about an unused field. We *could* turn off that warning for the field with `#[allow(dead_code)]`, or we could rename the field to `_dummy`, but I believe there's a better solution — `PhantomData`:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct ClipboardWithPhantomData { 
    marker: PhantomData<()>,
}

impl ClipboardWithPhantomData {
    fn new() -> ClipboardWithPhantomData {
        println!("Clipboard opened");
        ClipboardWithPhantomData { marker: PhantomData }
    }

    fn copy(&self) -> String { "copied".into() }
}

let c = ClipboardWithPhantomData::new(); // Correct
println!("{}", c.copy());

let c = ClipboardWithPhantomData; // Fails here
```

This doesn't generate any warnings, and `PhantomData` is used to indicate that something "different" is happening. I'd probably throw a little comment on the struct definition to note why we were using `PhantomData` in this way.

A lot of the ideas here stem from a semi-related [Rust issue about the correct type for an opaque struct](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27303).

Comment: Personally I think I’d prefer `_dummy: ()`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I'd love to hear more! I lean towards `PhantomData` as I read it as "this *should* have a `Foo` inside it, but cannot for some reason". Although I'd be a lot happier if it could be a `PhantomData<ClipboardAccessToken>` or something more self-documenting.

Comment: While it’s `PhantomData<()>`, it *can* store a `()`. I’m leaning toward “PhantomData should just about always contain a generic type” (e.g. `PhantomData<T>`, `PhantomData<*const T>`, *&c.*), though I haven’t checked usage or thought in great detail about it.